# Always get the full path of a relative file in bash

Tags: bash

I have a bash script located in /home/http/mywebsite/bin/download.sh

I have a config file in /home/http/mywebsite/config/config.yaml

Now I want to read the yaml file no matter where I execute my script.

The problem:
When I cd into /home/http/mywebsite/bin/ and run ./download.sh everything works.

When I cd into /home/ and run http/mywebsite/bin/download.sh it can not find the config file because of the relative path.

How do I make sure I can always read the config file no matter where I execute the script. It is always located 4 directories up from the script in config/config.yaml

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This will give me the root directory of my project which is /home/http/mywebsite/
fullpath="$( cd ../"$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
cat ${fullpath}config/config.yaml
```

This works if I execute it inside the directory where the script is.

If I execute the script from another directory such as /home/ I get the following error:

```
cd: ../http/mywebsite/bin: No such file or directory
cat: config/config.yaml: No such file or directory
```

Solution?

If it is possible it would be great with a code snippet that can traverse up a path N amount of times, this would solve my problem. But it is too advanced for me.

For example you can set a variable "cd_up=1" how many times to go up. The run the loop/sed or whatever magic.

And it would turn the absolute string from:
/home/http/mywebsite/bin/
into:
/home/http/mywebsite/

And changing it to 2 it would change the string to:
/home/http/

Comment: This might be a bit orthogonal to your question, but have you considered setting up an env var where your key files are located? You could then use rules such as current dir failing that env-based dir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve it finally by using:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
BASE_DIR=$PWD
# Root directory to the project
ROOT_DIR=${BASE_DIR}/../
cat ${ROOT_DIR}config/config.yaml
```

This allows me to execute the script no matter where I am.

Comment: Your first line is missing quotes: `cd "$(dirname "$0")"` should be safe even when `$PWD` contains spaces.  Also, `$PWD` is a lot faster than `\`pwd\``.

Answer (score 0):

You can use which command to determine absolute path of the executing script no matter where you are running

```
BASE_DIR=$(which $0 | xargs dirname)
ROOT_DIR=${BASE_DIR}/../..
cat ${ROOT_DIR}/config/config.yaml
```

Lets try printing the path from different locations.

```
-bash-4.1$ /tmp/dir.sh
$0 - /tmp/dir.sh. Absolute path - /tmp
-bash-4.1$ cd /tmp
-bash-4.1$ ./dir.sh
$0 - ./dir.sh. Absolute path - /tmp
-bash-4.1$
-bash-4.1$ cd /usr/bin
-bash-4.1$ ../../tmp/dir.sh
$0 - ../../tmp/dir.sh. Absolute path - /tmp
```

Comment: `$(dirname "$(which "$0")")` would be a better choice.  There's no need for `xargs` here, and we don't want any word-splitting.)

Comment: `which` isn't portable. There are many implementations; the original produced correct results for Csh, not your actual shell.